# Compile-time foreach outside function body

Tags: foreach, d, compile-time

Is there any way to have a foreach outside a function body for ex. generating code.

My scenario is that I have an associative array at compile-time that I need to use to generate specific fields. Unfortunately I can't really use a foreach outside of a function body to generate the members.

Right now I am using a work-around where I have a few mixins where I give one AA to the first mixin and that mixin converts the AA to an array and passes it to the second mixin, the second mixin is recursive with itself by ng itself until there is no more member, while also calling the first member in the array, which calls a third mixin that I can use to generate code.

It's not as smooth and dynamic as I really would want it to be and I was wondering if anyone has a better solution.

Here is my solution

```d
// First mixin that takes the associative array and a string for the mixin to handle the items
mixin template StaticForEachAA(TKey,TValue, TKey[TValue] enumerator, string itemMixin) {    
    enum array = arrayAA!(TKey,TValue)(enumerator); // Converts the AA to an array of key-value pair structs
    alias ArrayType = KeyValuePair!(TKey,TValue);

    mixin StaticForEachArray!(ArrayType, array, itemMixin); // Calls second mixin with the array
}

// The second mixin that "fake loops" the array
mixin template StaticForEachArray(T, T[] array, string itemMixin) {
    static if (array.length) {
        import std.string : format;

        mixin(format("mixin %s!(T, array[0]);", itemMixin)); // Mixins the itemMixin to handle the current item
        mixin StaticForEachArray!(T, array[1 .. $], itemMixin); // slices the array to remove the item we just handled
    }
}

// The third mixin that can be used to do whatever has to be done with item
mixin template StaticForEachItem(T, T item) {
    import std.conv : to;
    pragma(msg, to!string(item));
}
```

And to do the "fake foreach" for an associative

```d
enum AA = [0 : 1, 1 : 2, 2 : 3];

mixin StaticForEachAA!(int, int, AA, "StaticForEachItem");
```

This will print the key-value pairs from `AA` at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

Leveraging the power of compile-time functione excution (CTFE) you could make a helper function that generates code for you using the data from an associative array (AA) you provide.

```d
import std.string : format;

string generateCodeForEachAA(TKey, TValue)(TValue[TKey] data, string foreachBody)
{
  string result;
  foreach(k, v ; data)
  {
    result ~= format(foreachBody, k, v);
  }

  return result;
}
```

This function turns the given AA data into a string by formatting the given `foreachBody` with each AA element. The returned string can then be `mixin`'ed:

```d
enum Data = [ 0 : 1, 1 : 2, 2 : 3 ];

enum Code = generateCodeForEachAA(Data, q{ pragma(msg, "%1$s => %2$s"); });

pragma(msg, "Code: " ~ Code);

mixin(Code);
```

Output:

```
Code:  pragma(msg, "0 => 1");  pragma(msg, "1 => 2");  pragma(msg, "2 => 3");
0 => 1
1 => 2
2 => 3
```

Using this to generate members within a struct:

```d
struct Foo
{
  enum Members = [ "foo": 123, "bar": 42 ];
  mixin(generateCodeForEachAA(Members, q{ typeof(%2$s) %1$s = %2$s; }));
}

void main()
{
  import std.stdio : writeln;

  Foo f;
  writeln("foo: ", f.foo);
  writeln("bar: ", f.bar);
}
```

Output:

```
foo: 123
bar: 42
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach to it, thank you. Will see how it'll work out with this solution, prior to the other

Comment: Glad I could help. For further inspiration check the phobos sources, `std.typecons.Tuple` for example does something similar albeit without using AAs, but the techniques are still applicable.

Comment: It's not that I don't understand this approach, I do something similar already in the place I was gonna use the other approach, but thanks anyway